# "Hang out with friends" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, verb

How do I say

> I like hanging out with friends

in German? I'm having trouble with the verb "hang out" in this meaning. From the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-german/hang%20out), there are meanings of shirts/tongue hanging out, resisting etc. which are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Amongst young people, the word is **[abhängen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/abh%C3%A4ngen)**, which connotes that you spend a lot of time with your friends (e.g. in the playground) but that you usually do nothing meaningful (except for maintaining your relationships).

Comment: for sure you go to the playground for that....

Comment: Some words about the difference using the prepositons *mit* or *bei* may be needed to make this answer complete (this is meant for the case we link to this question in the future too).

Comment: Can i get an example, because i'm a little confused.

Comment: @Vogel612: I do know some local playgrounds that are, in the evening, occupied by drinking youths rather than the children the playgrounds are meant for.

Comment: StackExchange ist alt

Answer (score 13):

In my impression the words **abhängen** and **rumhängen** have been replaced by **chillen**. People in their twenties and older may still use abhängen and rumhängen (especially when talking *about* teens), but teens seem to use chillen much more often. I even think that abhängen and rumhängen sound pretty oldfashioned to teens (like *knorke* was oldfashioned and replaced by *cool* and so on…).

Answer (score 9):

I would say it's "Mit Freunden herumhängen", so "Ich mag es mit Freunden herumzuhängen". Yes, we use the same kind of words.

We even use the term "herumchillen" for that purpose, though that is more common among the youth. Since you would use this only among the youth, you may use it as well that. But keep in mind that it's very informal.